# How do I output messages to the Visual Studio output window, from MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, message

I have tried adding `<Message>` elements to tasks in a Visual Studio project file, in order to debug the build process. However, the elements have no effect on the text that is written to the Visual Studio output window.

Is there a way to write messages to the Visual Studio output window, by adding markup to the project being built?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329.aspx) may help:

> Under *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and
>   Solutions* → *Build and Run*, there’s the
>   *MSBuild project build output verbosity*
>   combo box. This controls how much info
>   you want to see in the Output window.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
Even with Importance="high", Messages don't get written out to the Output window by default.

Comment: Let it also be noted that if your custom task dll is built with the Release configuration, Debug.WriteLine's will be ignored. You must build in Debug for this to work. I just confirmed that

Answer (score 1):

In your project properties → *Build Events*, you can add something like this in the *Post-build event command line*:

`echo This is my message, no quotes required!`

And then you'll be able to see it in the Output after a successful build (if configured to run on a successful build, which is my case).

Comment: this can be used to print variable values in .csproj files.

Comment: How do you output the content of MSBuild properties, e.g. `Platform`, using this method?

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work (it used to for me): `<Message Text="blah" />`

(And of course, from code, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("blah");)

Comment: Debug.WriteLine() outputs to the debug console at *run-time*

Comment: That's why I put "from code" above, right?
Even more, nothing prevents you from writing a custom msbuild extension and use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(), right?